# Windows 7 Aero Peek of Tabs in Java Desktop App

Tags: java, windows-7, aero-peek

I would like to implement [Aero Peek](http://lifehacker.com/5077280/a-closer-look-at-windows-7s-aero-peek-feature) of tabs in my desktop application (as per the functionality provided by Internet Explorer and [this](http://windows7themes.net/firefox-3-6-windows-7-integration.html) Firefox extension).

I'm coding in Java, but appreciate that I may need to use some native hooks to get this working. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to write that feature in .NET managed code, you can use the [System.Windows.Shell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shell(VS.100).aspx) namespace introduced in .NET 4. This easy to use wrapper let me get my [Root Folders](http://blog.280z28.org/archives/2010/01/91/) utility up and running in no time.

Otherwise, the APIs are [Windows Shell COM interfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774328(VS.85).aspx) documented at MSDN.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Java library providing the new Windows 7 features for Java. It's called [J7Goodies](http://www.strixcode.com/j7goodies/) by [Strix Code](http://www.strixcode.com). You can create Windows 7 tabs for any GUI component and the library will do all the rendering for you.